# How to write a query to find records which do not belong the field selected?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have two database tables below:

Course_Module Table:

```
CourseId  ModuleId
1         1
1         2
1         3
```

Module Table:

```
ModuleId ModuleNo   ModuleName                            Credits
1        CHI2513    Systems Strategy                      20
2        CHI2550    Modern Database Applications          20
3        CHI2565    Ecommerce - Business and Technology   20
4        CHT2220    Interactive Systems                   20
5        CHT2520    Advanced Web Programming              20
6        CHI2554    Patent Law                            40
```

Now I do not know how to do this but what I want to do is create query where it will outputs a set of records which shows a list of modules which is not in the course selected.

So for example if the `CourseId = 1`, then the modules it should output from the query are these below:

```
4        CHT2220    Interactive Systems                   20
5        CHT2520    Advanced Web Programming              20
6        CHI2554    Patent Law                            40
```

This is because as you can see in the Course_Module table, these modules do not belong to the select CourseId `1`.

But how can a query like this be written? Below is just a simple query I have created:

```
SELECT cm.CourseId, m.ModuleId, m.ModuleNo, m.ModuleName, m.Credits
FROM Course_Module cm
INNER JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
WHERE
(CourseId = 1)
ORDER BY ModuleNo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following ?

```
SELECT
    m.*
FROM
    Module m
WHERE
    m.ModuleId NOT IN (
                       SELECT cm.ModuleId
                           FROM Course_Module cm
                       WHERE cm.CourseId = 1
                      );
```

Comment: tested it in phpmyadmin and it has worked beautifully. Thank you :)

Comment: Can I ask you a quick question, when I use `$mysqli->bind_result()` am I suppose to include the SELECT in the NOT IN ()? in other words should it be `$sessionqrystmt->bind_result($dbModuleId,$dbModuleNo,$dbModuleName,$dbCredits);` OR should it be `$sessionqrystmt->bind_result($dbModuleId,$dbModuleNo,$dbModuleName,$dbCredits, $dbCourseModuleId);`?

Comment: @Manixman The result will be 4 columns, so you can bind it to 4 `vars`. So use the first case. Think this link will help u, http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work:

```
SELECT
   Module.*
FROM
   Module
WHERE
   ModuleId NOT IN ( SELECT ModuleId FROM CourseId WHERE CourseId = 1)
```